Radius / Gauss curvature relation for geodesics of constant geodesic torsion
Analysing surfaces of revolution with geodesics possessing constant geodesic torsion $ \tau_g,$ can we write a relation
$$ K= k_1k_2 = a + b r$$ where $K$ is Gauss curvature,  radius $r$ in cylindrical coordinates, $ \tau_g= (k_1-k_2) \sin \psi \cos \psi$, and $(a,b)$ are constants?
This is only a hunch or just my conjecture.  Verified it as true by Mathematica numerical calculation as the $(K-r)$ plot is always straight. The surface turns out to be of positive $K$ having cusps as shown. The magenta arc runs tangentially between adjacent green cuspidal circles.
Can I request you please help with a proof or disproof?
Thanking you in advance.

EDIT1:
The above arose while attempting to define a arcwise disconnected toroidal volume halves of positive
and negative Ks placed alongside their cuspidal edges. The bottom green part could be of constant K negative.

